# An error in installing Caffe on OS X 10.11: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, gcc, 64-bit, caffe

I met a usual error—— symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64，but for an unusual reason. I have searched for a long time and found some methods，but they didn't work.

[image]

Anyone can help me?Thanks.there are some parameter about my Mac below:

```
# cc -v
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix

# gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

[image]

THX!!!